# html css how force break text line

Tags: line-breaks

As in subject. I want force to break line text like:

```
entercode&hereentercode&hereentercode&hereentercode&here
```

and automatically prevent width of column table to be changed by long not breakable text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML/CSS line break when text overflows container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158498/html-css-line-break-when-text-overflows-container)

Comment: “word-break:break-all” is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS rules `white-space:normal;` and `word-break:break-all;` to the text’s containing element.

Comment: word-break:break-all; works but is deprecated. white-space:normal; is not necessary.

Comment: @DarofromPoland “break-all” is not deprecated. You are thinking of “break-word”

Answer (score 0):

you need to add word-wrap: break-word; to your td tag

```css
.wrap-text{
   word-wrap: break-word;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>Text</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td class="wrap-text">entercode&hereentercode&hereentercode&hereentercode&here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not works. max-width can't be used because of column are different and dynamic. In one case have 255px in other have 200 and text must match to column width not width to text